# Looping through a string to check the value. (Java Calculator)

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I am trying to write a method that will look through a sting and add any numbers in the string to a `calcOperand` array and any operators to a `calcOperator` array. This is for my Javat calculator.

Below is the code I am stuck on. You can see that I have tried to create the method to split the `String` into an array and loop through it. I would then like to check the `String` to see if it's an operator or an operand. What is the best way to do this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class stringCalculator {

private String userinput;
private int[] calcOperator;
private char[] calcOperand;

public stringCalculator(String userinput){
    this.userinput = userinput;
    //System.out.println(userinput);
}   

//This function will check the input and return true if the user enters a correct expression.
public boolean checkInput(){
    boolean show = userinput.matches("[-+/*0-9]+");
    return show;
}

//This function will add any numbers in the string to the calcOperand array.
//and any operators to the calcOperator field.
public void parseInput(){
    String[] theinput = userinput.split("");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < theinput.length ; i++){
        if(theinput.charAt(i) == "+" ){
            calcOperator.add("+");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it a working code? If yes then post this for review in [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to break down an expression like this '4 + 2 - 1 / 3' into a

- int[] calcOperator = {4,2,1,3};
- char[] calcOperand ={'+', '-', '/'};

right?

you're doing nearly right! go through the user input and make substrings from start to end (don't split the string).

Hint: use dynamic data-objects instead of array!

```
private ArrayList<Integer> calcOperator = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Character> calcOperand = new ArrayList<Character>();

public void parseInput(){
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i ++){
        if (input.charAt(i) == '+'){
            end = i;
            String operator = input.substring(start, end).trim();
            int opAsInt = Integer.parseInt(operator);
            char operand = '+'; //as defined in the if-clause

            calcOperator.add(opAsInt);
            calcOperand.add(operand);

            //set index
            start = i + 1;
        }           
    }
    //last operatore would be missing right now, so add it!
    String operator = input.substring(start, input.length() ).trim();
    int opAsInt = Integer.parseInt(operator);
    calcOperator.add(opAsInt);
}
```

Comment: Hello @Ciaran Ashton, you need to implent the other operations as well, '-' and '/' and maybe even '%' ?

Answer (score 1):

Store the operands in calcOperand array operators in calcOperator array in the checkInput() method as follows:

```
public stringCalculator(String userinput) {
    this.userinput = userinput;
    checkInput();
}

// This function will check the input and return true if the user enters a
// correct expression.
public boolean checkInput() {
    String[] operators = userinput.split("[-+/*]"); 
    calcOperator = new int[operators.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < calcOperator.length; i++) {
        calcOperator[i] = Integer.parseInt(operators[i]);
    }
    String[] operands = userinput.split("[0-9]");
    calcOperand = new char[operands.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < operands.length; i++) {
        if (operands[i].length() > 0) {
            calcOperand[i] = operands[i].charAt(0);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking character with `" "`. We use `" "` for String. Try this

```
if(theinput.charAt(i) == '+' )
```

Also `calcOperator` is an array. Array doesn't have `add` method. I think you should use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 0):

theinput is a String array and you cannot call charAt() method on the string array. That is the problem with your code. Instead try the below code where strings of the array are individually compared with the string "+"

```
String[] theinput = userinput.split("");
for (int i = 0 ; i < theinput.length ; i++)
    {
        if(theinput[i].equals("+"))
        {
             calcOperator.add("+");
        }
    }
```